# How to create a draft post with images on a Wix blog via the Wix API?

Tags: post, blogs, velo

I have a publicly available blog on Wix and so far I've added all my posts via the Wix dashboard but now I'd like to use their API for this purpose. Everything works fine in the case of post headlines and content, but in no way am I able to add graphics to posts via the API. Theoretically, I do everything in accordance with the official documentation and I have tried probably all possibilities including the way presented below, but every time I check through the website, there is a title and content defined by me in the draft, however images are never added to it. Does anyone know a solution?

```
# Set up the API endpoint and headers
url = "https://www.wixapis.com/blog/v3/draft-posts"

headers = {
    "Authorization": "example_token_generated_from_wix_documentation_https://dev.wix.com/api/rest/authorization/oauth-2/request-an-access-token",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

# Set up the rich content of the blog post
rich_content = {
    "nodes": [
        {
            "type": "PARAGRAPH",
            "id": "",
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "type": "IMAGE",
                    "id": "",
                    "nodes": [],
                    "imageData": {
                        "type": "SITE",
                        "siteData": {
                            "url": f"https://static.wixstatic.com/media/image_id~mv2.jpg"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "paragraphData": {
                "textStyle": {"textAlignment": "CENTER"},
                "indentation": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "PARAGRAPH",
            "id": "",
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "type": "TEXT",
                    "id": "",
                    "nodes": [],
                    "textData": {
                        "text": "My blog post content goes here.",
                        "decorations": []
                    }
                }
            ],
            "paragraphData": {
                "textStyle": {"textAlignment": "AUTO"},
                "indentation": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}

# Set up the draft post data
data = {
    "draftPost": {
        "title": "My Blog Post Title",
        "richContent": rich_content,
        "heroImage": {
            "type": "SITE",
            "siteData": {
                "url": "https://static.wixstatic.com/media/123~mv2.jpg"
            }
        }
    }
}


# Make the API call
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

**UPDATE 1**
I thought that maybe the problem was due to the lack of access to the appropriate permissions and that's why only the text is visible in the draft post. Unfortunately, even if I load the image directly from the file, the graphics are still not visible even though the draft is added correctly and the status 200 is returned.

```
# Read the image data from disk and encode it in base64
with open('image.png', 'rb') as f:
    image_data = base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode()

# Set up the rich content of the blog post
rich_content = {
    "nodes": [
        {
            "type": "PARAGRAPH",
            "id": "",
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "type": "TEXT",
                    "id": "",
                    "nodes": [],
                    "textData": {
                        "text": "My example blog post content 1.",
                        "decorations": []
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "IMAGE",
            "id": "",
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "imageData": {
                        "image": {
                            "src": {
                                "base64": image_data,
                                "altText": "Example image"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "PARAGRAPH",
            "id": "",
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "type": "TEXT",
                    "id": "",
                    "nodes": [],
                    "textData": {
                        "text": "My example blog post content 2.",
                        "decorations": []
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "IMAGE",
            "id": "",
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "imageData": {
                        "image": {
                            "src": {
                                "url": "https://static.wixstatic.com/media/image_id~mv2.jpg",
                                "altText": "Example image",
                                "private": True
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}

# Set up the draft post data
data = {
    "draftPost": {
        "title": "My Blog Post Title",
        "richContent": rich_content
    }
}

# Make the API call
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
print(response.status_code)
# Check the response status code
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Blog post created successfully!")
    print(response.text)
else:
    print("Failed to create blog post: " + str(response.text))
```

**UPDATE 2**
I've noticed that when I define a node as shown below, there seems to be an image object in my post draft, but it's not visible at all and it looks like the screenshot shows. I have tried adding links from both Wix Media Manager and external sites, and I've made sure the images are available when I open links with them, but unfortunately the result looks the same every time. Any ideas?

```
{
            "type": "IMAGE",
            "id": "",
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "type": "IMAGE",
                    "id": "",
                    "nodes": [],
                    "imageData": {
                        "image": {
                            "src": {
                                "url": "https://static.wixstatic.com/media/2d7149_6b51eeb779cd460099e98e7ce2f14e1c~mv2.jpg"
                            },
                            "height": 1920,
                            "width": 1080,
                        },
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

[image: Wix Draft Post Image]

Comment: Where you able to solve it somehow? I've been stuck exactly with the same, I am able to post text, headlines, paragraph, seoData, however I am not able to do it with images or heroImage.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with my PHP script, and it's showing the image in blog properly. Hope it will help you.

```php
$post_field = [
            "draftPost" => [
                "title" => $topic->topic,
                "memberId" => $memberId,
                "heroImage" => [
                    "id" => $image["id"],
                    "url" => $image["url"],
                    "altText" => $topic->topic,
                ],
                "richContent" => [
                    "nodes" => [
                        [
                            "type" => "IMAGE",
                            "id" => "",
                            "imageData" => [
                                "containerData" => [
                                    "width" => [
                                        "custom" => "700px",
                                    ],
                                    "alignment" => "CENTER",
                                    "spoiler" => [
                                        "enabled" => false,
                                    ],
                                    "height" => [
                                        "custom" => "800px",
                                    ],
                                    "textWrap" => true,
                                ],
                                "image" => [
                                    "src" => [
                                        "private" => false,
                                        "url" => $image["url"],
                                        "id" => $image["id"],
                                    ],
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            "type" => "HTML",
                            "id" => "",
                            "htmlData" => [
                                "containerData" => [
                                    "width" => [
                                        "custom" => "750px",
                                        "spoiler" => [
                                            "enabled" => true
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                    "height" => [
                                        "custom" => "12000px"
                                    ],
                                    "alignment" => "CENTER"
                                ],
                                "source" => "HTML",
                                "html" => "{$topic->fullBlog->content}"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                "media" => [
                    "displayed" => true,
                    "wixMedia" => [
                        "image" => [
                            "id" => $image["id"],
                            "altText" => $topic->topic,
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            "publish" => true,
            "fieldsets" => ["URL"]
        ];
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?